# How to integrate qTest with selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, qtest

Want to integrate qtest with selenium testing framework. Can I get the steps from scratch ? Or if there is any sample project

I have Qtest API's , however not sure about how to access qtest and how to integrate with framework.